# Create Database link to MS SQL Server on Oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, gateway, dblink, heterogeneous-services

Please help.. I need to connect to a SQL Server database (B) from an Oracle database (A) which are both on Windows server machines. Here is what I did.

System DS created on (A):-
Name: ISECWM
Driver: ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Test Results:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 12.00.5543
>
> Running connectivity tests...
>
> Attempting connection Connection established Verifying option settings
>   Disconnecting from server
>
> TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!

$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/initISECWM.ora file contains

> HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = ISECWM 
>   HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora updated:-

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =     (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME=`ISECWM`)
>         (ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\11g)
>         (PROGRAM=`dg4odbc`)
>       )   )

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora updated:-

> WORLDMAP.DBL =    (DESCRIPTION=
>     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=`SERVER A HOSTNAME`)(PORT=1521))
>         (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=`ISECWM`))       (HS=OK)     )

Database link created:-

> CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK TSTDBLINK CONNECT TO  "sql server
>   username" IDENTIFIED BY "sql server password" USING 'WORLDMAP.DBL';

Tested the database link with:-

> select * from dual@TSTDBLINK; --gives the error

Error:-

> ORA-28513: internal error in heterogeneous remote agent ORA-02063:
>   preceding line from TSTDBLINK
>   28513. 00000 -  "internal error in heterogeneous remote agent"
>   *Cause:    An internal error has occurred in the Oracle remote agent
>              supporting a heterogeneous database link.
>   *Action:   Make a note of how the error was produced and contact the
>              customer support representative of the agent vendor. Error at Line: 7 Column: 20

Comment: Did you reload the listener with `lsnrctl reload`? You might want to read [this step-by-step set of instructions on Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/heterogeneous-services-generic-connectivity).

Comment: What is version oracle? Oracle 11.2 have transparent gateway(tg4mssql) for MSSQL.

Comment: Add diagnostic information   `lsnrctl status`   `lsnrctl service`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, finally Oracle helped me with the issue.

It seems I had 2 homes, I put the initISECWM.ora in the wrong Oracle home.

Just copied and pasted it in the other home/hs/admin/ and it worked like a wonder! Voila!